# Remove .xls extension on excel file created with xlsxwriter on django

Tags: python, django, excel, xls, xlsxwriter

I wrote a really simple django project to test xlsxwriter. I can open the excel file, but when I name the file 'filename.xlsx', the file is downloaded as 'filename.xlsx.xls'. How can I fix this?

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .excel import get_excel


def home_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=filename.xlsx'
    excel_data = get_excel()
    response.write(excel_data)
    return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLX is an OpenXML format, so the mimetype is different, it uses:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

you thus should change this to:

```
def home_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse(
        content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    )
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=filename.xlsx'
    excel_data = get_excel()
    response.write(excel_data)
    return response
```